# How do you check if two numbers are within a threshold of each other?

Tags: ruby, integer, comparison

I need to check if an image's content length has changed. However, there are some images that seem to oscillate within about 15 or 20 bytes. So I want to say: "these two images are effectively the same if their content length is within 25 bytes".

Let's say that I have two numbers: `first` and `second` that are positive integers and a `threshold` that is also a positive integer. What is the simplest way to determine if the two numbers are within the threshold of each other?

Comment: Man I love StackOverflow! Thanks everyone! I knew it was simple but for some reason my brain was over-complicating it... I was doing a conditional to figure out which was bigger and thought there must be a simpler way.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
def in_range(hi, lo, range)
  (hi-lo).abs <= range
end

in_range(5, 10, 3) #=> false
in_range(7, 10, 3) #=> true
```

And it's pretty fast regardless of range

```
puts Benchmark.measure{ 10_000.times{in_range(50_000, 1_000_000_000, 53000)} }
#=>0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000936)
```

Answer (score 3):

Check whether their absolute difference is in the threshold,

```
(first - second).abs <= threshold
```

Or check whether their distance is between `-threshold..threshold`, like so:

```
(-threshold..threshold).cover?(first - second)
```

or so:

```
(first - second).between?(-threshold, threshold)
```

Comment: benchmark your 2nd version, it's 10x slower than 1st version,with small ragne and gets exponentially worse with large ragne.

Comment: It's about 2.5 times slower for me (mostly range initialization) and it does not get exponentially worse, because this is not how ranges are implemented in Ruby.

Comment: you modified your answer since I commented that, but that's good because it now performs much better

Answer (score 0):

Other option, using [Enumerable#include](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.5.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-include-3F):

```
(x1 - delta..x1 + delta).include? x2
```

Where `x1` is the first point, `x2` is the second point and `delta` is the threshold.

Comment: Benchmark this.  It can be up to 75% slower than a simple `<=` comparison depending on the range.